# Patching different Adobe Flash versions

Tags: flash

I have several systems with Flash issues, all with different installations of Flash.

Now, my vulnerability scanner has identified and advised solution on the issues, but as I have different version installations of Flash, the advice is also wildly different for each.

My question is- if I update each system to the latest possible for each server, will installing the latest supersede all the Flash installations advised by my vulnerability scanner, and resolve all the vulnerabilities? Or do I have to piecemeal install patches according to the vulnerability?

Comment: This is not so much a security question than a Flash patching question. The details are up to Adobe.  Why not uninstall all the old ones and install the latest, if you are not sure?

Comment: You should always install the latest versions - although even then you cannot be 100% secure - because of 0-day exploits.

Comment: “resolve all the vulnerabilities?” - You didn’t list which vulnerabilities were discovered.  So what I typically would do is patch to the current version then run the vulnerability scanner again.